# Text aligment cursor problem in user Input field (WIX sites)

Tags: user-input, textfield, velo, cursor-position

I'm creating my own site on the Wix platform, and I met one problem. When I'm setting up text alignment to the right side, after starting typing, the cursor moves to the left side of the text, but I want to make it usual and keep it on the right side (with left and center text alignment it works fine). I can't find any setting in Wix, to fix this.
I don't think that I can add custom CSS code in WIX elements, but I can add some JS code there/

[Cursor problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPjgK.png)

I would appreciate any help

Comment: I experience the same issue. Did you find out what was causing it and how to fix it?